# Dictionary object is shown as HashTable during runtime

Tags: .net, windbg, jit, sos

[DataColumnCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumnCollection.cs) class has a columnFromName field that is defined as Dictionary of string and DataColumn as shown below

```
public sealed class DataColumnCollection : InternalDataCollectionBase {

        private readonly DataTable table;
        private readonly ArrayList _list = new ArrayList();
        private int defaultNameIndex = 1;
        private DataColumn[] delayedAddRangeColumns;

        private readonly Dictionary<string, DataColumn> columnFromName;     
....
```

When I see this object in memory, its shown as a Hashtable (image below).
[image]
I have used Dictionary object in many applications that are shown as Dictionary in Windbg/Sos also. How come this Dictionary is getting translated into a Hashtable?

Comment: Maybe different versions of .NET?

Comment: This uses .NET version 4.0. I am not sure which different version are you referring to?

Comment: I meant maybe you're using different versions of .NET across the multiple applications you've written. Maybe in versions prior to 4.0 Dictionary shows as Dictionary but later versions show it as Hashtable.

Comment: Both of these are using .NET 4.0